# How can i stop pygame.time.set_timer?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to print the message 3 times. After then how can i stop pygame.time.set_timer in this example?

```
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
 
print_message = pygame.USEREVENT + 0

pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 1000)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == print_message: 
            print("stop now ")`
```

Comment: The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the _time_ argument of [`pygame.time.set_timer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the *time* argument of [`pygame.time.set_timer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer):

```py
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
 
print_message = pygame.USEREVENT + 0
pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 1000)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == print_message: 
            pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 0)
```

The `pygame.time.set_timer` also has an additional _loops_argument:

> loops is an integer that denotes the number of events posted. If 0 (default) then the events will keep getting posted, unless explicitly stopped.

If you want to get just 1 singe event, call `pygame.time.set_timer` with argument 1:

```py
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
 
print_message = pygame.USEREVENT + 0

pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 1000, 1)  # <---

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == print_message: 
            # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

this might not be the best solution but you can set the variable "print_message" to some thing else when you want it to stop

like this:

```py
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
 
print_message = pygame.USEREVENT + 0

pygame.time.set_timer(print_message, 1000)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == print_message: 
            print("stop now ")
            print_message = 0
```

Comment: No this is not the way to stop the timer event. The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the _time_ argument of [`pygame.time.set_timer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)